# $this->redirect works local but not online

Tags: cakephp, redirect

[this is cakephp]

on a function called `getfile($id)` in a controller named PublicacionesController I have `$this->redirect("../" . $file['file']);` which redirects to a file to open it. I have tested echoing $file['file'] and it's okay. The problem is that instead of opening the file it justs redirects to .../publicaciones/getfile/$id.

I see that some people are having fun downvoting this so I will post the entire function:

```
 function getfile($id){
            Configure::write('debug', 2);

            $fileDir = opendir(APP . 'webroot' . DS . 'files');

            while($entryName = readdir($fileDir)) $files[] = $entryName;
            closedir($fileDir);

            $filesResult = array();
            $arrSort = array();

            $classTypes = array(
                'jpg' => 'img',
                'png' => 'img',
                'gif' => 'img',
                'jpeg' => 'img',
                'bmp' => 'img',
                'doc' => 'doc',
                'pdf' => 'pdf',
                'xls' => 'xls'
            );

            foreach($files as $file){
                //preg_match("/.+_([$id])_[0-9]{8}.+[doc|pdf|xls]/i",$file,$fileMatch);
                preg_match("/($id).+[doc|pdf|xls|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp]/i",$file,$fileMatch);
                if(count($fileMatch)){
                    $props = explode('_',$file);
                    $ext = explode('.',$file);

                    $index = count($filesResult);

                    $filesResult['i'.$index] = array(
                        'file' => "files/{$file}",
                        'date' => date('d/m/Y',filectime(APP . "webroot/files/{$file}")),
                        'ext' => $classTypes[$ext[count($ext)-1]]
                    );

                    $fileDate = filectime(APP . "webroot/files/{$file}");
                    $index = count($filesResult)-1;
                    $arrSort['i'.$index] = $fileDate;
                }
            }

            arsort($arrSort);
            $filesResult = array_merge($arrSort,$filesResult);
            $file = $filesResult['i0'];

            //echo $file['file'];
            //die();

            $this->redirect("../{$file['file']}");
        }
```

This works fine locally, any ideas?

Comment: This looks very very unconventional and if it was easy to break/abuse. as your question proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a space after the ending php tag. wohoo....